# Angular 6 - null, undefined check not working -ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Region' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, null, undefined

This Kendo-dropdownlist exists as a Kendo Grid column.

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="regions"
                     [textField]="'Region'"
                     [value]="'RegionMasterID'"
                     [formControl]="formGroup.get('Region')"
                     [filterable]="true"
                     (valueChange)="handleRegionChange($event, dataItem)"
                     (filterChange)="handleRegionFilter($event)">

 </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Here is component code:

```
handleRegionChange(value: any, dataItem: any) {

 if ((dataItem.Region !== null || dataItem.Region !== undefined) && value.Region) {
            this.SelectedRegion = value.Region;
            dataItem.Region = value.Region;
            dataItem.RegionMasterID = value.Region == "" ? '' : value.RegionMasterID;
        }
        else {
            this.SelectedRegion = '';
            dataItem.Region = '';
            dataItem.RegionMasterID = '';
        }

        this.update(dataItem);
    }
```

In handleRegionChange event, I’m trying to check if user made any selection. If yes, then if-block otherwise else block.
If user clicks the dropdown and is not making any selection, dataItem.Region is null, but the instead of executing the else block, error is thrown in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Region' of undefined
```

Please guide how to resolve the issue